# How to reassign a type to a variable in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to reassign a different type to a variable in typescript without creating a new variable?

```
let variable: string | number;


//somewhat like one of those not working examples
declare let variable: string;
varaible: string;
```

Comment: Not possible directly, control flow analysis will narrow the type on assignments (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAbghgTgSxgI1ALggZzIgdgcwgB8JcBXAW2RDgG4AoWRFUCCAXggCIuGmlUIAHTIE+ABQBKCAHoZEBJiw4EBCEA)/ type guards (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAbghgTgSxgI1ALggZzIgdgcwgB8JcBXAW2RDggF4IBZGMACwDo4ZcATAewoAKAJQQAfBAAM7AKwQA-BABESiGgCMAbgBQCAGaCwATwAOIPnujwkqEPToMl2PPiWiA3tojeriFKHZkBHwRCAB6MIgETCwcBAIIbQBfCBBgTDtPH18bALA+AFEADxM+XBBcMCRgUIiomPIqGmSgA):

Comment: If you use the *any* variable type, you will achieve the result you mentioned - the variable will change type at runtime depending on the assigned value.

Answer (score -1):

if you control the values and ensured that everything is correct, you can use simple javascript's type convertation:

```
let variable: string | number = "1";
variable = Number(variable) // here your type will be number
```

Comment: My question provides a simplified problem, ofc I know how to parse primitives in js, but this does not narrow the type of variable as shown here: 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/DYUwLgBAbgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwgHwmgrgLYBGISA3AFCUD0NAAmPALQoZoD2SIlUEAvBAByRUkgAUUAJTU6KeAjApgwCBwDWvARABEAQ3gATHUA